# Windows 11 will not "Combine taskbar buttons and hide labels"

Tags: windows-11, taskbar

Despite the fact that I have that option set to "Always", the icons do not automatically combine and collapse into squares the way they were a couple of days ago. I've searched around but I wasn't able to find anyone experiencing the same problem with Windows seemingly ignoring any choice you make.

It seemed to start after installing Cumulative Update Preview for Windows 11 Version 22H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5030310). I'm assuming that's not a coincidence.

Comment: Try uninstalling the update, that particular update, changed several things directly associated with the start menu and taskbar

Comment: Working here - newest Windows 11 build. Try running DISM / SFC to see if that helps.   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem until now. The new Taskbar settings for grouping/ungrouping didn't work.

- Before Windows Update, that introduced "Combine taskbar buttons and hide labels" setting, buttons always been grouped.
- After the update, buttons always been ungrouped and the setting "Combine taskbar buttons and hide labels" did nothing.

Moreover, taskbar layout behaviour was strange and buggy after the update. Sometimes there was plenty of space, but apps were hidden under `[...]` button, sometimes buttons on the right side have had strange width, etc.

I accidentally found how to fix this problem. There was `DWord` key `NoTaskGrouping` in the Registry under this path:

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```

I set the value for this key to `0` and restarted `explorer.exe`. And suddenly ungrouped taskbar started to behave properly and "Combine taskbar buttons and hide labels" setting started to work (yay!). Now I can group/ungroup the taskbar buttons!

I hope this helps someone.

Presumably, this setting somehow interferes with the new updated Windows 11 settings (i.e. "Combine taskbar buttons and hide labels").

Answer (score 1):

It was the update. Sorry to bother everyone, but it didn't occur to me until about 5 seconds after posting my question that I might be able to uninstall the update, and that did it.

For those who are curious, it was optional, and the main feature of this update is that it added the Microsoft version of ChatGPT as an app that was automatically tacked to the taskbar. I'm already using it with Edge Canary, so I don't think I'll miss this update and I'll definitely wait until they've got the kinks out.